# Datastore keeps on retrieving after the data is populated

Tags: powerbuilder

In the datawindow report's detail section, there was a computed field and inside the computed field is the PB function which holds 2 string passed by value arguments and a return type of string. Once the retrieving is finished and data is populated, the datawindow keeps on retrieving as I've watched from the SQL profiler but there was no error message window.

What seems to be the problem in this function?

```
/*
    Function name : f_generate_serialrange
    Return Type : String
    Argument Type   :       Argument Name   :
    String                  loc
    String                  id
*/

Long ll_row
Double ld_serialno1, ld_serialno2, ld_start, ld_end, ld_result, ld_next, ld_prev = 0
Double ld_row, ld_count = 0, ld_countaccept = 0, ld_serialcount
String ls_sum, ls_start, ls_prev, ls_next, ls_serialno2

DataStore lds_getserial

lds_getserial = Create DataStore
lds_getserial.DataObject = 'dw_delivery_receipt_serialno1'
lds_getserial.SetTransObject(SQLCA)

lds_getserial.Retrieve(loc,palletid) 

ll_row =lds_getserial.RowCount() 

IF lds_getserial.RowCount() > 0 THEN
  FOR ld_row = 1 TO lds_getserial.RowCount() 
    ld_serialno1 = Double(lds_getserial.GetItemString(ld_row,'serialno'))
    ls_serialno2 = lds_getserial.GetItemString(ld_row,'serialno2')

        IF ld_count = 0 THEN
            ld_start = ld_serialno1
            ls_start = ls_serialno2
            ld_count++
        ELSE
            ld_next = ld_serialno1
            ls_next = ls_serialno2
            IF ld_prev = 0 THEN 
                ld_result = ld_next - ld_start
            ELSE
                ld_result = ld_next - ld_prev
            END IF

            IF ld_result > 1 THEN 
                IF ls_prev = '' THEN
                    ls_sum += String(ls_start) +'~n'
                ELSE
                    ls_sum += String(ls_start) +' - '+String(ls_prev)+'~n'
                END IF

                ld_start = ld_next
                ls_start = String(ls_next)
                ld_prev = 0
                ls_prev = ''
            ELSE 
                ld_prev = ld_next   
                ls_prev = String(ls_next)
            END IF
        END IF
    NEXT

    IF ls_prev = '' THEN
        ls_sum +=String(ls_start)+'~n'
    ELSE
        ls_sum +=String(ls_start)+' - '+String(ls_prev)+'~n'
    END IF
END IF
//MessageBox('System Message','Serial Range has been successfully retrieved.',INformation!)

Destroy (lds_getserial)
RETURN ls_sum
```

Comment: You are talking about a datawindow but the code handles a datastore. I was thinking your problem might be related to the `retrieve.asneeded` property, but this does not apply to datastores.

Comment: You mean it is not recommended to place a function with a datastore inside in the datawindow report? Is it because the datastore will continue to retrieve though the data is already populated?

Comment: No. There is a feature of the datawindow when used visually (it may be not visible though) in a datawindow control on a window or user object: when the `retrieve.asneeded` property is activated, the DW only retrieves the records corresponding to the visible lines. Then later when scrolling the dw the missing rows are retrieved to display. I though it could be your problem but that case does not apply to a datastore (= a non visible datawindow) declared / instanciated in a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call a function that uses the database in a computed field because many things will cause PowerBuider to calculate the computed field again. Instead add a dummy column to the DataWindow's SELECT statement. After you retrieve you can loop through the rows and use code similar to your function to populate the dummy column with the serial number range. The reason I say "similar to your function" is that you should only create and connect the DataStore once, then retrieve it with the parameters for each row.